# sbt behind local artifactory proxy

Tags: sbt, artifactory, ivy

When setting up a sbt project with a local artifactory / maven proxy I see the following message:

> In order to specify that all resolvers added in the sbt project should
>   be ignored in favor of those configured in the repositories
>   configuration, add the following configuration option to the sbt
>   launcher script:
>
> ```
> -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
> ```
>
> Add the following to your build.sbt file:
>
> ```
> resolvers += 
> "Artifactory" at "http://url/artifactory/virtualRepository/"
> ```

But what I would like to achieve is a behaviour similar to maven i.e. not manually overriding resolvers in the SBT file, but rather via the configuration.
Is this possible as well? If yes how?
Desired  behaviour

- the project should compile fine without local artifactory proxy
- when available / configured in repositories the local one should be used as the source / cache for quicker access

currently, I only get unresolved dependencies for sbt plugins:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scalariform#sbt-scalariform;1.6.0: not found
[warn]  :: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.0: not found
[warn]  :: org.scalastyle#scalastyle-sbt-plugin;0.8.0: not found
[warn]  :: net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.8.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

With warnings of

```
[warn]  module not found: org.scalariform#sbt-scalariform;1.6.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalariform/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scalariform/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   d:\users\heilerg\.ivy2\local\org.scalariform\sbt-scalariform\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\1.6.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://url/artifactory/virtualRepositoryScala/org.scalariform/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://url/artifactory/virtualRepositoryScala/org/scalariform/sbt-scalariform_2.10_0.13/1.6.0/sbt-scalariform-1.6.0.pom
[warn] ==== Artima Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.artima.com/releases/org/scalariform/sbt-scalariform_2.10_0.13/1.6.0/sbt-scalariform-1.6.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.0 ...
```

and SBT logs will show

```
 [ERROR] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:766) - IO error while trying to download resource 'repo1:org/scalariform/sbt-scalariform_2.10_0.13/1.6.0/sbt-scalariform-1.6.0.pom': org.artifactory.api.repo.exception.maven.BadPomException: The target deployment path 'org/scalariform/sbt-scalariform_2.10_0.13/1.6.0/sbt-scalariform-1.6.0.pom' does not match the POM's expected path prefix 'org/scalariform/sbt-scalariform/1.6.0'. Please verify your POM content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven repository root path.
```

Somewhere people mention to use the following option in Artifactory to *"suppress POM consistency checks"*, but in the current version of artifactory I can not finde such an option.

## edit

I can see only these options
[image]

Comment: Seems to be more of an artifactory issue:
https://github.com/coursier/coursier/issues/286
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6235
A workaround mentioned is to "suppress POM consistency checks"

Comment: where can I find this option? In the current artifactory there does not seem this option in the advanced tab of a remote repository. Please see the edit. I can see only the options from the screenshot above.

Comment: The User Guide says: " in the Admin module, go to Repositories | Remote and click it to display the Edit Repository screen."
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories

Comment: thanks for the hint. The answer (unlike many links suggest) is to look for the file in the basic settings.

Comment: Must be an old artifactory Version I guess :P

Comment: Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: Nah, its fine. Just one more thing; I'm not sure if this was what you were asking for, but you can specify the proxy in the $userhome/.sbt/repositories file. It should then get picked up globally by all sbt projects

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the comment, a common workaround is "Suppress POM Consistency Checks" - [Advanced Settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Advanced+Settings).

If that is not desirable, another method might be to re-publish the plugin with a valid POM. I've written [POM consistency for sbt plugins](https://eed3si9n.com/pom-consistency-for-sbt-plugins) to show that can be done.

```scala
// set some unique postfix
ThisBuild / version := "0.15.0-Pets1"
 
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "sbt-assembly",
    ....
 
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    // add this
    pomConsistency2021DraftSettings,
  )
 
// Add the following
lazy val pomConsistency2021Draft = settingKey[Boolean]("experimental")
 
/**
 * this is an unofficial experiment to re-publish plugins with better Maven compatibility
 */
def pomConsistency2021DraftSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  pomConsistency2021Draft := Set("true", "1")(sys.env.get("POM_CONSISTENCY").getOrElse("false")),
  moduleName := {
    if (pomConsistency2021Draft.value)
      sbtPluginModuleName2021Draft(moduleName.value,
        (pluginCrossBuild / sbtBinaryVersion).value)
    else moduleName.value
  },
  projectID := {
    if (pomConsistency2021Draft.value) sbtPluginExtra2021Draft(projectID.value)
    else projectID.value
  },
)
 
def sbtPluginModuleName2021Draft(n: String, sbtV: String): String =
  s"""${n}_sbt${if (sbtV == "1.0") "1" else if (sbtV == "2.0") "2" else sbtV}"""
 
def sbtPluginExtra2021Draft(m: ModuleID): ModuleID =
  m.withExtraAttributes(Map.empty)
   .withCrossVersion(CrossVersion.binary)
```